# Pandas read_csv wrong separator recognition

Tags: pandas

I am trying to open csv file in pandas using read_csv function. My file have the following structure a row with headers where each column header's name have the name underlined with quotes for example `"header1";"header2";` non headers values in columns contains int or string values without quotes with only ; delimiter.  Dataframe has the following structure 
`"header1";"header2";"header3";
value1;value2;value3;`
When i apply read_csv `df = pd.read_csv("filepath", sep=";", engine="python")` i am getting `ParseError: expected ';' after ' " '` help to solve it

Comment: Could you add an example of what a non-header row in the csv file looks like?

Comment: Taking the time to check out [mre] will help you to improve this question. So will https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Non header column contains int or string values with ; separator for example dogs; cats; etc

Comment: For test, include the quotechar parameter ad change quotes for single quotes: 
`df = pd.read_csv('filepath', sep=';', engine='python', quotechar=' " ')` *** don't include spaces in the parameter's value. I do for clarity.

Comment: I did it the same ParseError: expected ';' after ' " '

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify column names as follows, and see if it resolves the issue:

```
col_names = ["header1", "header2", "header3"]
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=";", names=col_names)
```

If this doesn't work, try adding `'quotechar=' " '` and see